# Eslint on git submodule, how to overwrite parent config

Tags: javascript, reactjs, git, eslint

I want to use eslint inside it and on father, my objective is to use a pipeline on my core since there are many hands on it, but it's getting a configuration of the parent project, how I can avoid it?

````
> core@0.1.0 lint
> eslint ./src/**/*.{js,jsx} --fix


- client\core\node_modules\eslint-plugin-react\index.js (loaded in ".eslintrc.js")
- client\node_modules\eslint-plugin-react\index.js (loaded in "..\.eslintrc.js")

Please remove the "plugins" setting from either config or remove either plugin installation.

If you still can't figure out the problem, please stop by https://eslint.org/chat/help to chat with the team.```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve that just use root: true on your eslint config on current directory and parent